# What is the scope of using rsync in sync-ing my target root file system from my host?

Tags: embedded, rsync

I have a target and host setup with Linux as the OS on both.

I have a root file system(`RFS`) in my target. I have a setup in which my RFS is in development state so it will undergo changes on the fly. My requirement is that, every time I make a change, I need to sync my current RFS to my target RFS.

One of my colleague suggested that I can use `rsync` to attain my task.

Please shed your valuable suggestions on this idea.
All other ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: Do you want to manually sync it (ie, like Gille's answer) or do you want a solution that will sync automatically anytime a change is made?  I don't recommend this, but it is possible.

Comment: @Seven: If it is possible to do it automatically i would also like to know that.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of access do you have to the target? If you can ssh into it, it's just

```
rsync -au "$RFS" target:/
```

Note that you'll need an `rsync` executable on the target as well.

You'll want to set up some kind of passwordless authentication. I guess during development you would just allow root so ssh in, and put a public key for root in place. If the ssh server on the target is OpenSSH, then you need `PermitRootLogin Yes` in `/etc/sshd_config` (or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or something), and the root public key would be in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `/.ssh/authorized_keys` depending on where root's home directory is set in `/etc/password`.

If you changed the bootloader, and perhaps if you changed the kernel, you'll also need to run the bootloader update utility.